# How do I remove everything outside of parenthesis in a string using regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

How do I remove everything outside of parenthesis in a string using regex. I'm just trying to get what's in the parenthesis.

I'm looping through a bunch of records. To keep things simple for this example, I'm using just 1 record (each record can have multiple values).

So if this my record string:

```
<cfset servicelist = "Orthopedic, Joint (AFDA); Orthopedic Surgery (ACDA)">
```

What regex do I add to this variable:

```
<cfset Codes = "">
```

I'm trying to grab the following codes out of the record:

(AFDA)(ACDA)

Comment: Try `ReReplace("#CodeList#",".*?(\(\w+\))?","$1","All")`

Comment: Yep.  FYI, in CF backreferences are `\1` instead of `$1`

Comment: <cfset Codes = ReReplace("#ServiceList#", ".*?((\w+))?","\1","All")>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This should do it **`(\(\w+\))`***

***https://regex101.com/r/ns3HYN/2***

**`\(`** matches the character **`(`** literally (case sensitive)
**`\w+`** matches any word character (equal to **`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`**)
**`+`** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
**`\)`** matches the character **`)`** literally (case sensitive)

[image]

---

*Also Try [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) Example* `.*?(\(\w+\))?`** and replace with **`$1`*** (or `\1` in ColdFusion)

> [image]

**`.*?`** matches any character (except for line terminators)
**`?`** Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible

Comment: Doesn't that bring back everything but what I want? I want whats in the parenthesis. <cfset Code = ReReplace("#CodeList#","(\(\w+\))","","All")>

Comment: @FSUKXAZ - 1. First, you are using a different expression than they suggested 2. Why bother with `ReReplace`? Just use the suggested expression with `ReMatch`. It returns an array, which you can easily convert into a string with list functions.

Comment: This is true, but I don't like arrays. It also requires more lines of code. I used ReReplace to set a variable that returns everything but what's in the parenthesis in just 1 line of code. <cfset ServiceName = ReReplace("#ServiceNameList#","\(([^\)]+)\)","","All")>  I was looking for something similar for grabbing what is inside the parenthesis.

Comment: `.*?(\(\w+\))?` Replace with $1

Comment: Why put *my* suggestion into *your* answer, even without any comment on how it works?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew lol `:-)` I will edit later, -  It has been a crazy day

Comment: @FSUKXAZ - No, code-wise it is [about the same](http://trycf.com/gist/c32508f21950d62c3505cbc416b354fe/acf2016?theme=monokai). ReMatch is a little less verbose and *bit* more intuitive than using ReReplace to replace everything *except* what is matched. Granted, it all depends. Some of it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: After reviewing all your responses @WiktorStribiżew had most of code and Leigh added the "\" so it would work in CF. I brought it home adding it the variable I mentioned in the original post. So basically what I was looking for was this: <cfset Codes = ReReplace("#ServiceList#", ".*?(\(\w+\))?","\1","All")>  Thanks to everyone.

Comment: This was that actually worked for me `.+?(\([\w ]+\))?` include the `[  ]` allowed me to include other chars in addition to the alphabetical (w), such as the space character